# How can I express "composition" in Protégé?

Tags: ontology, semantic-web, protege

I'm building an ontology in Protégé for data sharing management in IoT environments. For this purpose I want to create a package that contains the observation (raw data), information on its provenance, and the licence that the data consumer will need to accept and respect to be able to use the ressource. The aim of our project is to make this "package" the entity that will be circling between users rather than just the raw data, and therefor for the data owner/producer to not completely lose his ownership once his data is shared.

In order to do this, I created rather spontaneously a class named "Package" composed of three disjointed classes which are: the observation, its provenance information, and the generated licence. However, I realized that this does not mean "a package is composed of those three elements", but rather "each one of those three elements is a package", which is not at all what I'm seeking.

[image]

Is there a way to express the composition, without (for example) having to create an Object Property named "isComposedOf" ?

Thank you in advance for your time. Please don't hesitate if you need other details

Comment: The semantics of OWL does not support composition in the way you see it, which seems to be similar to composition in UML class diagrams. In fact there are issues with composition in UML class diagrams and in general association/attribute is what is meant when people use composition. However, association/attributes will require the introduction of additional object/data properties. I have written about this on my [blog](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/mathematical-formalization-of-object-orientation/).

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse I see. Thank you for these precisions and your time